# How to keep medical coverage for pre-existing conditions when changing jobs in California

Tags: united-states, california, health-insurance

I'm sorry for this question being so strange. I'm shaking while I write it. This is very hard.

My mom has really bad cancer. She is in remission, but there is a relatively high chance it will be back within the next three years.

Prior to this she was seeking compensation from her work from a pretty horrific workplace accident. Slipped, bashed her face in, shattered teeth and bone.

Her work made it very difficult for her to keep up her employment while seeking compensation. The appointments they made her do (sanity tests to see if she slipped on purpose, paperwork, etc.) , paired with the appointments she had for dealing with her cancer made her hire a lawyer to help with that part of her life.

During discovery the lawyer representing her work yelled at her. Asked about her cancer (unrelated to her injury). Asked her how many kids she had. Then he just outright told my mom that she was going to be fired. Shortly after she was terminated.

Cobra is like 1800 USD a month. We can't afford her treatment without it. I'm looking online to see if my mom can get a new job, anywhere, and get coverage. It's so complicated.

Comment: She has a lawyer so should consult them. And if she's not happy with the employer's lawyer's conduct she could consider [making a complaint with the State Bar](https://www.calbar.ca.gov/public/complaints-claims)

Comment: I thought the  Obama care law did away with pre-existing conditions not being covered ?

Comment: A company fired someone who has cancer... And had a workplace injury in California? (of all places in the US, California).

Is she suing them?

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments.

@Rick Thank you. I'll tell my mother about filing a complaint.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I thought so too, but I can't find a clear and concise answer (I also have not been sleeping well, I think my mind is slipping)

Comment: @Questor She was suing them for coverage of her injury. They wanted her to take a lump sum. It was a pretty gruesome injury to her face. She wanted any complications taken care of in the future. We want her to file for wrongful termination, but the whole experience has kind of broken her. Its like signing her up for even more trauma.

Comment: See https://www.hhs.gov/healthcare/about-the-aca/pre-existing-conditions/index.html. Federal site says no insurance can charge more or deny coverage for pre existing conditions